# How to do a Join query using the pivot table and another table using the FK

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I have set up my relationships like below

**User model**

```
public function branches() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Branch', 'branch_user', 'user_id', 'branch_id');
}

public function reservations() {
    return $this->hasMany('Reservation');
}
```

**Branch Model**

```
public function users() 
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'branch_user', 'branch_id', 'user_id');
}
```

**Reservation Model**

```
public function branches() {
    return $this->BelongsTo('Branch');
}
```

A branch has many reservations and a branch belongs to a branch.

Please How can I do the below query

```
select table_number from reservations r
JOIN branches b
ON b.id = r.branch_id 
JOIN branch_staff bs
ON bs.branch_id = b.id  
WHERE bs.user_id = 1
```

using Eloquent?

I have done the above query like this

```
DB::table('reservations')
->join('branches', 'branches.id', '=', 'reservations.branch_id')
->join('branch_staff', 'branch_staff.branch_id', '=', 'branches.id')
->where ('branch_staff.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
->select('reservations.table_number', 'reservations.active')
->orderBy('reservations.table_number', 'asc')
->get();
```

using the query builder.

**Relationship**
[image]
But how can I do this using Eloquent especially when I have define the relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Answer wouldn't be possible without @Vokemike

I kept getting collections error with $reservations that was because branches returns a collection so to solved this I had to loop over it and this was how I did it

```
$user_branch = Auth::user()->branches;

    foreach ($user_branch as $branch) {
       return $branch->reservations()->orderby('reservations.table_number', 'asc')->lists('table_number');
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think you may have set your models up incorrectly. From your SQL it looks like a user has one branch, not many. And if a reservation belongs to a branch you would call the method 'branch' and not 'branches'.

I would set the models up like so:

**User model**

```
public function branch()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Branch');
}
```

**Branch Model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User');
}

public function reservations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Reservation');
}
```

**Reservation Model**

```
public function branch() {
    return $this->belongsTo('Branch');
}
```

You can then grab a list of ordered Auth::user()table numbers for a branch staff member with the following code:

```
$tableNumbers = Auth::user()->branch->reservations()->orderby('reservations.table_number', 'asc')->lists('table_number');
```

Comment: thanks for the reply and sorry for my late reply. I tried that but got "Call to a member function reservations() on null"

Comment: Without creating the code, I can't think what is wrong. It sounds like you're not getting any branches returned. Try making sure that you are getting branches. Auth::user() of course relies on a user being logged in.

Comment: @VotemikeI think i know what is wrong but don't know how to solve it. Please look in the image. The branch_user is the pivot table. So if a user belongs to a branch doesn't that mean i need the user_id in the branches table? Please remember that a user can be allocated to 1 or many branch(es).

Comment: You should be able to use `belongsToMany()` as you were. It wasn't clear in your original question that you had a pivot table. You should of course update your 'branch' to be 'branches'.
The [Laravel documentation on Eloquent many to many relationships](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships) is quite good and should help you.